# How do i get the same object with a class in SCSS?

Tags: css, ruby, sass

I have this code:

```
input[type="text"] {
    color: red;
    .blue {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

That gives me this

```
input[type="text"] {
    color: red
}
input[type="text"] .blue {
    color: blue;
}
```

How do I get something like this?

```
input[type="text"] {
    color: red
}
input[type="text"].blue {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Have you read the Sass tutorial?  http://sass-lang.com/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the *parent selector* (`&`):

```
input[type="text"] {
    color: red;
    &.blue {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: nice thats what i was looking for... i did not found it at tutorial. Thanks!