# Selecting current element in Sass

Tags: sass

Does Sass have a selector to refer to the element at the current nesting level? That way duplication like this could be avoided:

```
.something {
    color: red;
    a {
        color: red; // a tags are already styled globally
    }
}
```

And I could write this instead.

```
.something {
    self, a {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i get the same object with a class in SCSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155962/how-do-i-get-the-same-object-with-a-class-in-scss)

Comment: That question is different, I want to set the style regardless of whether something has a class or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a good new feature in the Sass 3.3  - @at_root

```
.something {
    &, a {
        color: red;
    }
 }
```

More variants of using this feature you can find here:

https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/774

Comment: Awesome! Could you explain what #{&} does?

Comment: #{ something here} - it is a simple interpolation,  & - link to the parent element